# PHP: Multidimensional array to HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an HTML using PHP associate array. My function looks like:

```
function generateTable($associative_array){
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>';
echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($associative_array)));
echo '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach ($associative_array as $row){
    array_map('htmlentities', $row);
    echo '<tr valign="top"><td>';
    echo implode('</td><td>', $row); 
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

AND my associative array generated is like this:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(3) { 
    ["Objective"]=> string(21) "Product Catalog Sales" 
    ["Targeting Group"]=> array(3) { 
      [0]=> string(31) "female Age 18-24 28.73% cheaper" 
      [1]=> string(31) "female Age 25-34 28.18% cheaper"  
      [2]=> string(30) "female Age 35-44 4.51% cheaper" 
    } 
    ["Placement"]=> array(3) { 
      [0]=> string(33) "mobile_feed iphone 30.62% cheaper" 
      [1]=> string(45) "mobile_feed android_smartphone 19.58% cheaper"  
      [2]=> string(33) "right_hand desktop 21.48% cheaper" 
    } 
  } 
  [1]=> array(3) { 
    ["Objective"]=> string(11) "Conversions" 
    ["Targeting Group"]=> array(6) { 
      [0]=> string(31) "female Age 18-24 28.73% cheaper" 
      [1]=> string(31) "female Age 25-34 28.18% cheaper" 
      [2]=> string(30) "female Age 35-44 4.51% cheaper" 
      [3]=> string(31) "female Age 18-24 14.41% cheaper" 
      [4]=> string(31) "female Age 25-34 14.75% cheaper" 
      [5]=> string(30) "female Age 35-44 6.14% cheaper" 
    } 
    ["Placement"]=> array(4) { 
      [0]=> string(33) "mobile_feed iphone 30.62% cheaper" 
      [1]=> string(45) "mobile_feed android_smartphone 19.58% cheaper"  
      [2]=> string(33) "right_hand desktop 21.48% cheaper" 
      [3]=> string(33) "right_hand desktop 58.77% cheaper" 
    } 
  }
}
```

The table structure is being generated, but it is unable to input the values, below is the error that is displayed: can someone please help how to modify the function.

> Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Make sure all the values are strings and not arrays/objects

Comment: it would be difficult to collect all values as strings.I need to collect some of them as arrays

Comment: You could use serialize() or something similiar to display them as text. Or you could loop through the inner array and create a sub-row so to speak. I don't know any decent solutions for this to be honest, its always a bit odd

Comment: Not the source of your warning, but your code does not output or assign the result of `array_map()`, which does not operate on arrays by reference. So this line of code is redundant?

Comment: you should use array_walk_recursive .

Comment: @kamlesh.bar, I'm not too sure of array_walk_recursive.. can you help me ?

Comment: If you want to recursively apply `htmlentities` to all elements of your `$rows` array, you can do the following (note that the value is passed into the callback by reference and is reassigned, updating the value in the original array) - `array_walk_recursive($row, function(&$value) { $value = htmlentities($value); });`.

Comment: All that said, I am not sure how you want your function to work exactly - do you want to generate a flat table structure from a multi-dimensional array? You'll need a different approach.

Comment: you have to put 2 things one that @DarraghEnright said and another recursive implode function.

Answer (score 1):

Before applying any escaping or quoting functions to this complex construct, get yourself a idea of what the result should look alike. That's a two- to three-dimensional array. It has, on the second level, both strings and another array. Furthermore, it's a mixed flat and associated array.

So your "row" isn't a row at all, but a complex associative array itself.

I suggest to create objects from the second level on:

```
class AdsSpec {
  private $objective;
  private $targetGroup;
  private $placement;
   ...
  function getObjective()
  { 
    return $this->objective;
  }
}
```

etc. And then

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($associative_array as $obj) {
   $ads = new AdSpec($obj['Objective'], $obj["Targeting Group"], $obj["Placement"]);
   $newArray[] = $ads;
}
```

furthermore:

```
foreach ( $newArray as $adsObject )
{
 ...
    echo htmlentities($adsObject->getObjective());

 ...
```

This would clear the array stuff and separate rendering from the object itself.